# Unable to view HomePage URL at Google Consent Page

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am unable to view HomePage URL at the consent page
Example : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=http://dracuno.shuthub.com/&response_type=token&client_id=394813307106.apps.googleusercontent.com

Only email is being shown in developer's information
Whereas i have saved HomePage URL in developer console

Can anyone help me with this
OR tell why is this so ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the Email address displayed to the users on the oauth consent screen the first thing you need to do is add this email address in the project. 
`Google Developers Console -> Permissions`

Add this new email address as a member to the project give it the permissions `is owner`   Should be a company Email address probably support@something.com

Then in the `Google Developers Console -> APIs & auth -> Consent Screen`   you will see Email Address at the top. To change that to the email address you just added.

Comment: I want Homepage URL to be displayed with Email
Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes web page is set in the consent screen to

Comment: Check the link i have mentioned in the question
once more : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=http://dracuno.shuthub.com/&response_type=token&client_id=394813307106.apps.googleusercontent.com

It's developer info holds no webpage URL

Comment: You need to change it in your application registered with Google.  https://cloud.google.com/console

Comment: @DalmTO This is my configuration : [img](http://dracuno.shuthub.com/myconf.jpg)
So according to the documentation i should see the homepage link in consent page
But i am unable to

Comment: @user3314614 your right I just checked I think they changed something.  I logged it as a bug, Privacy policy URL and terms of service URL also aren't showing.  See if they get back to me.